# Markov Fields as Markov Chains

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I am currently looking through the literature on a topic that has so far appeared only in Georgii's Gibbs measures, chapter 10.

The question really is, how do I construct a Markov Chain from a given Markov Random Field? The opposite is not difficult and I have found references for that already. But the reverse is more interesting. I have to add, I am looking for a rather gentle introduction resp. reference. I am not prepared to think about $\lambda$-configurations.

Any suggestions?